# typical three way SYN Handshake is followed by a FIN-ACK

Tags: networking

I have an application that works when the Client and Server are on the same subnet. When they are on a different subnet the typical three way SYN Handshake is followed by a FIN-ACK.
A typical sequence looks like this:

[image]

What should I look for to determine what might cause the application to send the FIN-ACK when the Client is on a different sub net?

Comment: Remember that Client/Server is an applications concept, and TCP creates a connection between TCP peers that have no concept of clients or servers. A TCP sends a FIN when the application tells the TCP it will no longer send any data. It must still listen and process data from the other side until the other side send its own FIN or RST. You should read _[RFC 9293, Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9293)_ that is the TCP definition, and it has an explanation of the TCP state machine.

Comment: Using Sysinternals-Process Monitor I was able to confirm that the application process is issuing a "Thread Exit" then "TCP Disconnect" so its not the Firewall.
Unfortunately the application log doesn't give a reason it just says "Thread Exiting". There is also two blank lines in the application log before and after the "Thread Exiting" message. It looks like the app is trying to say something but fails.  I keep pushing the vendor. They have at least escalated the issue.